# Explanation of why 棋 is included in 琴棋书画?

Tags: phrase

I feel like this is a case of `One of these things is not like the other`.

The Four Arts of the Chinese Scholar are 琴、棋、书、画 ...

Therefore,

- 琴 : `Musical instrument = great`
- 书 : `Calligraphy        = great`
- 画 : `Painting           = great`

These three no problems at all, all very sophisticated...

But how about 棋? What? 圍棋? Go? A board game? Seriously? Really? Go?

How can 'Go' be part of the `Four Arts of the Chinese Scholar`?

Comment: isn't Go sophisticated? Much much more than chess!

Comment: @user58955 I never thought of any board game as being "sophisticated"...it's a game, no?!

Comment: but it has a high degree of complexity, an intellectual challenge.

Comment: @user3306356 You are using modern mentality to measure something that's considered an intellectual art form historically. Here lies the issue.

Comment: Which one of the four is not a game, and why does it matter?

Comment: @deutschZuid and why is it "considered an intellectual art form historically"?

Comment: @user3306356 Do some research yourself.

Comment: @deutschZuid +1! excellent answer! riveting response! clearly shows insight! wow! blown away!

Comment: Go would be "sophisticated" enough. Deep Blue defeated Kasparov many year ago, while even with much interest of programmers and mathematicians, as far as I know, a Go program hasn't been able to defeat an unknown professional Go player (I mean any player who gets dan grading from Chinese/Korean/Japanese Go Association) yet.

Comment: @Stan You might want to look into AplhaGo. AI is certainly better at Go than humans these days, but your comment was true up to just a few years ago!

Comment: Well, one could even argue that how does knowing how to play a musical instrument, (represented by 琴) makes one a "scholar", then and now? I think a "scholar" was an all round adept or conversant with a variety of "arts", a kind of what we call a "cosmopolitan". So, a  scholar was not someone who is good at only calligraphy, painting and music, (the "soft, sensitive" side), but the "hard, intellectual" represented by being good at playing 棋. BTW, 棋 was a scholarly pursuit played by the well off leisure classes of people, not peasants who had no time nor inclination for pursuing the "arts"

Comment: @OlleLinge Aha! Years passed, the world has changed. It's AlphaGo telling/warning us that the AI era is coming ... And now I become a deep learning engineer (mainly on computer vision) :P

Comment: @Stan You're back?!

Comment: @Mo. Not yet. Maybe two or three years later when I'm not busy in my job. ... And let's not chat in comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No particular reasons. It is considered as an art for ancient chinese, though the "art" in ancient China has not the same meaning of the modern "art", or even the occidental "art".

Answer (score 9):

One may, of course, argue that Go is a *very* sophisticated game. While a 30-node supercomputer could already beat a world chess champion in 1996, supercomputers with hundreds of cores were unable to beat a Go Master *without handicaps* [until 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Go).

However, your question is invalid, not because Go is a highly intellectual game, but because *"the Four Arts of the Chinese Scholar"* is a mistranslation of the term 四藝 ("four arts").

The Chinese character 藝 can refer to various skills, arts or crafts. E.g. 武藝 means "martial arts" and 工藝 means "crafts". Those arts or skills that are more intellectual and do not require much labour or physical strength fall inside the category of **文藝** (literally "literary arts", but it includes other intellectual or art activities/skills than writing novels or poetries). Some people nowadays translate the word 文藝 to "scholarly arts", but this is a poor translation if not wrong. Twisting "scholarly arts" into "arts of scholars" is a further distortion.

Even if we put the translation issues aside, there is no such thing as "**the** Four Arts of the Chinese Scholar" in classical Chinese. The phrase "琴棋書畫" did appear in ancient Chinese literature, but it was not meant to be representative of "scholarly arts". The earliest known appearance of the phrase is in the calligraphy commentaries 法書要錄 (circa 780 AD) written by 張彥遠. [The relevant sentence](https://archive.org/stream/06067704.cn#page/n220/mode/2up) says that

> "辯才博學工文，琴棋書畫皆得其妙。"
>
> "Biàncái was erudite and skillful in various 文藝; he knew the very essence of musical performance, chess, calligraphy and painting."
>
> (Remark: the 辯才 here is not the word for "eloquence" but the name of a person).

So, the author merely wrote that Biàncái was good at many 文藝 and they happened to be 琴, 棋, 書 and 畫. He didn't claim or imply that 琴棋書畫 were **the** four most representative 文藝 activities in Biàncái's or his own times.

In the prose 閒情偶寄 (1671), the author 李漁 did call 琴棋書畫 "the four arts". [He wrote](https://archive.org/stream/02097228.cn#page/n108/mode/2up):

> "以閨秀自命者，書、畫、琴、棋四藝，均不可少。"
>
> Those whose viewed themselves as ladies must know four arts, namely, calligraphy, painting, musical instruments and chess.

Yet, these are at best "the four arts of **ladies**", not "the four arts of **Chinese scholars**".

At any rate, Go is clearly an intellectual activity that should be classified as 文藝 instead of 武藝 or 工藝.

Comment: +1 for the sources. But the argument at the end is weak: "以閨秀自命者，書、畫、琴、棋四藝，均不可少", here "knowing four arts" is only the **necessary condition** for 閨秀, but it never suggests "the four arts of ladies".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Go is as simple as you thought...As user58955 has mentioned
It's not just a easy board game..It takes a lot of time to master it.
Besides these, 围棋 is a traditional Chinese game and 琴棋书画 is a conventional word.

Answer (score 0):

下棋好也是聪明的表现吧，有一个聪明的头脑何尝不是一件值得赞扬的事呢？